# Many-to-Many Relationship (with properties) in Google App Engine for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, many-to-many, relationship

I understand from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/relationships?csw=1#Unowned_Relationships) on unowned relationships that the app must use sets of Key objects on either side of the relationship. This makes perfect sense.

Coming from many years of RDBM-style programming, though, I'm pretty confused about how I can model properties of that relationship itself.  For example, if I have entities **Category** and **Entry** in my many-to-many relationship and would like to persist a `dateAdded` property, or some other data that are only relevant when both sides of the relationship are known.

I suppose it would be possible to create a third class: **CategoryEntry** that links the two, but this seems like a kludge.

What is the proposed way to model this kind of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'relation table' such as you describe, is the standard solution - both in the RDBMS world and in the App Engine datastore - to having a relation with properties. It's not a kludge, because when the relation has attributes other than its existence, it requires somewhere to represent that.